# How do I handle variations in HTMLControl Inner Text in a Page Object Pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, ui-automation

Here is a little background on the specifications of my project:

- We use Specflow and Microsoft CodedUI Framework for UI Automation
- I have built a PageFactory that combines three Abstract Base Classes : BasePage, BaseMap, and BaseValidator that all Maps, Pages, and Validators inherit
- Our Application that we are automating has numerous workflows that make defined HTML Controls have different InnerText Values (HTMLComboBoxes for example)
- Everything is and needs to be abstracted from the actual Specflow Test Code in the Page Object Pattern, no unique code can exist within a Specflow Step

In my Maps I have certain controls like a combobox that has an InnerText change if a certain workflow is selected. I need to build assertion and verification statements to make sure the InnerText is correct for the workflow that is selected. This is not a problem. However, I do not want to just define a new variable for every InnerText change(There are A LOT).

Is there any way I can account for the InnerText variations in the Page Object Pattern and not have to code a new variable for every single one?

Here is an example of a Map Entry:

```
        public HtmlComboBox NextActionControlDropDownList()
    {
        var NextActionControlDropDownList = new PropertyExpressionCollection {
            new PropertyExpression(HtmlComboBox.PropertyNames.Id, "MEDCHARTContent_EmmpsContent_nextActionControl_ActionDropDownList", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo)
        };
        return Window.Find<HtmlComboBox>(NextActionControlDropDownList);
    }
```

This is the Base Control definition. It can also be this:

```
        public HtmlComboBox NextActionControlARFormalComplReview()
    {
        var NextActionControlARFormalComplReview = new PropertyExpressionCollection {
            new PropertyExpression(HtmlComboBox.PropertyNames.Id, "MEDCHARTContent_EmmpsContent_nextActionControl_ActionDropDownList", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo),
            new PropertyExpression(HtmlComboBox.PropertyNames.InnerText, "--Select Action-- Return to USARC ", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo)
        };
        return Window.Find<HtmlComboBox>(NextActionControlARFormalComplReview);
    }
```

My thoughts so far were to maybe make another map and inherit it? But that wouldn't solve my initial problem of too many variables for a single control. I don't see how If statements would help either because it needs to be defined for the framework to find the control. Maybe I could store the differing values in a collection of sorts and have a parameter key value to access them... but that seems like I would run into a lot of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try and see the methods under `PropertyExpressionOperator` you would see something called `Contains`.

```
new PropertyExpression(HtmlComboBox.PropertyNames.InnerText, "--Select Action--", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains)
```